# Negative matching using grep (match lines that do not contain foo)

Tags: regex, grep

How do I match all lines not matching a particular pattern using `grep`? I tried this:

```
grep '[^foo]'
```

Comment: [^error_log] would never ever work anyway, [] are char classes, regexp 's in general are not good at negative patterns (unless the engine implements negative lookaheads).

Answer (score 2349, accepted):

`grep -v` is your friend:

```
grep --help | grep invert
```

> -v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines

Also check out the related `-L` (the complement of `-l`).

> -L, --files-without-match only print FILE names containing no match

Comment: Worth mentioning that for multiple (negative) matches `-e` option can be used: `grep -v -e 'negphrase1' -e 'negphrase2'`

Comment: Similar to the comment from @Babken-Vardanyan Also - able to use pipes to join multiple matches e.g. `grep -v 'negphrase1|negphrase2|negphrase3'`

Comment: Last comment is NOT the same as it will search for things that don't match both rather than either.  ie If it matches one but not the other its still printed.   Try it both ways with non-similar strings

Comment: seems like if we have `grep1 | grep2 -v`, then -v effect takes place on grep1 too, so first do `grep not expected` and then `grep expected`

Comment: @EvanLanglois -  forcing grep to interpret the pattern as an extended regular expression using `-E` works, i.e.  `grep -vE  'negphrase1|negphrase2|negphrase3'`

Comment: @Zlemini - Yes, that will work, but the line by Nicholas Adams doesn't.

Comment: There's one use case this solution does not work for: If I want the _filename_ of the files with lines containing `foo` but not `bar`.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt, I think I misunderstood your scenario in my previous comment, the following may be what you're looking for `grep "" /dev/null * | grep foo | grep -v bar | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u` ([why the first grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12194352/3848), there's always a way :))

Comment: grep --help | grep "invert"

Comment: Tip: If you tried around and still can not filter anything, consider piping the errors to your grep as well for example `sudo opensnoop 2>&1 | ggrep -vE "^dtrace"`

Comment: Wow. Most  linux command uses `-v` for verbose... thes makers of grep use it for something that, if used unintentionally, will almost certainly mean malfunction...

Comment: This madlad out here grepping the help output from grep.

Comment: @YouriKoeman https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/j9q2nu/grep_grep_grep/

Comment: @Zlemini hit it on the head for simplest, working solution (IMHO).  Directory for mime types changed between versions (LMint) and I'm looking for a concentration of files defining the <file>.xml entries.  Locate gives me a great list, but without exploring excludes in its return I just focused on removing excess terms using a grep pipeline.  This works great, just as intended,
 locate mime | grep -e share | grep -vE 'timeshift|icon|Papirus' | wc -l  (933 lines) where  locate mime | grep -e share | grep -v 'timeshift|icon|Papirus' | wc -l (581126 lines).  Job done!

Answer (score 217):

You can also use `awk` for these purposes, since it allows you to perform more complex checks in a clearer way:

Lines not containing `foo`:

```bash
awk '!/foo/'
```

Lines containing neither `foo` nor `bar`:

```bash
awk '!/foo/ && !/bar/'
```

Lines containing neither `foo` nor `bar` which contain either `foo2` or `bar2`:

```bash
awk '!/foo/ && !/bar/ && (/foo2/ || /bar2/)'
```

And so on.

Comment: That's actually quite cool. You don't even have to learn the complete awk language in order to group regexp with logical operators. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: The OP specifically asks for `grep`. Why is this upvoted?

Comment: It's possible that the OP wasn't aware of `awk` capabilities and providing an alternate solution that provides the same result is helpful.

Comment: The awk command syntax you outline is very clear -- but I must be doing it wrong as it's not working for me!  I'm trying to select certain lines of output from a locate command. Each line should not contain either of 'icon' or 'timeshift' or 'Papirus' to reduce output for clarity.  This does not work:  locate mime | awk '!timeshift && !icon && !Papirus' | wc -l , producing 58234 lines.  A revised grep command produced 933 lines which is the correct output.  Wonder where I strayed? Or maybe it's a change in or different version of awk?  GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)

Comment: @OldUncleHo you need to enclose the string within `/ /`, so that Awk sees is as a string. Otherwise, it will treat `timeshift` and the other values as variable names. All together, you need to use `awk '!/timeshift/ && !/icon/ && !/Papirus/` or using some regex-fu `awk '!/(timeshift|icon|Papirus)/'`.

Answer (score 23):

In your case, you presumably don't want to use grep, but add instead a negative clause to the find command, e.g.

```bash
find /home/baumerf/public_html/ -mmin -60 -not -name error_log
```

If you want to include wildcards in the name, you'll have to escape them, e.g. to exclude files with suffix .log:

```bash
find /home/baumerf/public_html/ -mmin -60 -not -name \*.log
```

Comment: while one is going to use `mmin` to search for files modified within `60 mins`, use `-type f` too as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33410471/2361131