# BASH: make an array of all directory names in a directory that DON'T have a certain pattern in the name

Tags: bash

I have a directory that contains a bunch of .zip files as well as their unpacked version. I need to get a list of all the directory's and ignore the .zip files. How can I do this?

I am thinking of using `grep` and `ls`, but am not sure how to put it together.

Comment: `ls | grep -v "\.zip"`

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548453/negative-matching-using-grep-match-lines-that-do-not-contain-foo

Comment: Parsing `ls` is fragile and unsafe. See [Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) specifically the bottom section about `extglob`.

Comment: and to store it in an array? would it be myarr=$(ls | grep -v "\.zip")?

Comment: @EtanReisner so how would you do it? Getting the list of filenames I described?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get a list of all sub-directories and store it into an array:

```
shopt -s nullglob
dirs=( */ )
```

Comment: I used this, but then when I tried `echo $dirs` all I got was one out of the many subdirectories in the working directory.

Comment: You need to use `echo "${dirs[@]}"` to list all directories.

Answer (score 5):

If you can turn on `extglob` like so:

```
shopt -s extglob
declare -a files=( !(*.zip) )
```

See more about bash pattern matching on the [Pattern Matching man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html).