# Search file on Unix using find command

Tags: linux

I want to search for all files in the entire directory structure that have
been modified in the past 10 days and display their type:

```
find / -mtime +10 -exec file {} \;
```

Will this command work or do I need any modification?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find files modified in last x minutes (find -mmin does not work as expected)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407344/how-to-find-files-modified-in-last-x-minutes-find-mmin-does-not-work-as-expect)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the following command:

```
find /folder -type f -mtime -10 -print
```

Then adjust the rest of the command for your purposes.