# How do I send an email with file information in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, email

I'm currently working on a script where I have to send an email with this information:

- List of files backed up.
- **What files were recently modified? Say 1 or 2 hours.**
- Size and location of the backup in the host.

This is what I have done so far:

```
echo "Message" | mailx -s "Subject" -a path/ofthe/file.tar aaa@mail.com
```

This sends a mail with attaching the .tar file but I need to know what files where changed, if there were any.

Comment: For files modified look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407344/how-to-find-files-modified-in-last-x-minutes-find-mmin-does-not-work-as-expect

Comment: This is much too broad. Google the individual questions, then tell us where exactly you get stuck gluing the pieces together.

Comment: For other info. check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4887607/5265615

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tar -tvf path/ofthe/file.tar > /tmp/files.txt
cat /tmp/files.txt | mailx -s "Subject" -a path/ofthe/file.tar aaa@mail.com; rm /tmp/files.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*" -mmin -60|grep -v "^.$"
```

Find the current folder and change the file within 60 minutes