# Deleting a line in a textfile based on keyword in RUBY

Tags: ruby, file

I am working on creating a program which stores users in a textfile, and would love to delete/modify a line based on a keyword. This is the code I have right now for searching a keyword, which in return will print the whole line containing the keyword:

```
        keyword = File.readlines('skier_info.txt')
        matches = keyword.select { |name| name[/#{search}/i] }
```

I'm wondering how I can use this small bit of code to write every line from the textfile over to a new one, except for the one line I get from the "matches" variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the least amount of modification from your code :

```
keyword    = File.readlines('skier_info.txt')
no_matches = keyword.reject { |name| name[/#{search}/i] }

File.open('new_skier_info.txt','w+'){|out| out.puts no_matches}
```

[reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject) is the opposite of [select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) :

```
(1..10).reject{|x| x.even?}
=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

If your input file is big and you don't want to read it all in memory :

```
File.open('new_skier_info.txt','w+') do |out| 
  File.foreach('skier_info.txt') do |line|
    out.puts line unless line =~ /#{search}/i
  end
end
```

You could also use [`grep -v`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548453/negative-matching-using-grep-match-lines-that-do-not-contain-foo) in terminal ;)

Comment: It's a bit unfortunate to read the entire file into memory when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

So you can already identify the line(s) you want to remove? That's 70% of the work. Almost there!

Now all you need to do is create a new file and write to it all lines from the existing file, except the ones you don't need. After you're done writing the new file, you can copy it over the old one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sergio! I am very new to Ruby, so I don't know exactly how to do this... Could you please help me a bit more?:)

Comment: @VetleOttemFrantzvaag: being new is not an excuse for not using search. Take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777802/how-to-write-to-file-in-ruby

Comment: Bad formulation by me. My problem is not writing a file, but how I would go through selecting each line from the file, except the one I searched for.

Comment: @VetleOttemFrantzvaag Ah, that's easy. Use `reject` instead of `select`.