# How to delete lines not ending with '.org'

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file with a list of domain names(each on a seperate line).
How do I remove the lines not ending in `.org` using bash or python?
This is what I have so far which kind of works but not fully. This list will then be used later in python.

```
grep .org output1.txt
```

Comment: Please, read the man page of `grep`. (Google will also help because some people put man pages on web sites.) `grep` has a specific option to reverse the pattern matching.

Comment: grep -v .org output1.txt

Comment: But how do I delete that output from the file?

Comment: Maybe you need to look at the big picture.  Is there really any point to deleting the data from the file when a future python script could easily ignore those lines in the file as it is processed?

Comment: you write a new file, i.e. `grep '\.org' output1.txt > output1.org` If your determined to have only one file (test first!), then you can use `mv output1.org output1.txt` . Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negative matching using grep (match lines that do not contain foo)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548453/negative-matching-using-grep-match-lines-that-do-not-contain-foo)

Comment: @Joe, actually, this question is not even negative grep. It's just grep. "Remove lines not matching" == "Print lines that match"...

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
anything.org
anything.com
anything.org
anything.net
anything.com
anything.org
anything.net

$sed -i '/.org/!d' file

$cat file
anything.org
anything.org
anything.org
```

Comment: This is a bit dangerous. It will keep lines such as `http://fundacionborges.com.ar`. For a safer command, you can use `sed -i -e '/\.org$/d!' file`

Answer (score 0):

**Perl one-liner**

```
cat file
anything.org
anything.com
anything.org
anything.net
anything.com
anything.org
anything.net

perl -lne 'print if !/.*org/' file

anything.com
anything.net
anything.com
anything.net
```

---

Prints all lines that do not contain `org` at the end.
If you add `-i`  it makes it **edit in-place** and delete that line.
`perl -i -lne 'print if !/.*org/' file`

Answer (score 0):

The question apparently wants to remove the lines from the file.

```
ex file <<eof
g/[a-np-z][a-qs-z][a-fh-z]$/d
w
q
eof
```

will do that, assuming it is all lowercase.