# regex - match string not containing other string

Tags: regex, grep

I need to grep my logs for a particular string, but want to exclude strings that contain word "centrifugo".

for example, If I grep for `xxx` I get this:

```
123 centrifugo 551 xxx
451 abcd xxx 334
yyyy xxx 231
```

Expected Output:

```
451 abcd xxx 334
yyyy xxx 231
```

What's the regex for that?

Answer (score 2):

An easier answer than having a single Regex that matches all lines containing `xxx` but not `centrifugo` would be to first `grep` for `xxx` then pipe the output into another `grep` filtering lines that contain `centrifugo`. This could be written something like this:

```
grep xxx | grep -v centrifugo
```

For grep -v, also look at [Negative matching using grep (match lines that do not contain foo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548453/negative-matching-using-grep-match-lines-that-do-not-contain-foo#3548465)

Now, if you really want to use a Regex, take a look at [Regular expression for a string containing one word but not another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953039/regular-expression-for-a-string-containing-one-word-but-not-another). Applying that you can use a Regex such as this:

```
^(?!.*centrifugo).*xxx
```

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/LB0d8R/1).