# How to grep multiple negative strings

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file.

I want to grep for entries that DO NOT have str1 AND str2 AND str3 in it. Having a hard time getting this command.

Comment: See the `awk` answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548453/negative-matching-using-grep-match-lines-that-do-not-contain-foo?rq=1

Comment: Can you give an example? I can't tell if you want `hello str1` included or not ("yes, it should be included because it doesn't contain str1 and also str2 and also str3", "no, it should be excluded because it contains either str1 or str2 or str3")