# How to find text files not containing text on Linux?

Tags: linux, find, text-processing

How do I find files **not** containing some text on Linux? Basically I'm looking for the inverse of the following

```
find . -print | xargs grep -iL "somestring"
```

Comment: Belongs on SuperUser or unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: This does not work correctly if one of the file or directory names contains a white space. Use `find . -type f -exec grep -iL "somestring" +` (or `grep -r`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using grep to find files that don't contain a given string pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748129/using-grep-to-find-files-that-dont-contain-a-given-string-pattern)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The command you quote, ironically enough does exactly what you describe.
Test it!

```
echo "hello" > a
echo "bye" > b
grep -iL BYE a b
```

Says a only.

---

I think you may be confusing -L and -l

```
find . -print | xargs grep -iL "somestring"
```

**is** the inverse of

```
find . -print | xargs grep -il "somestring"
```

By the way, consider

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 grep -iL "somestring"
```

Or even

```
grep -IRiL "somestring" .
```

Comment: accepting your answer, it's recursive and inverse of find I wanted: grep -IRiL "somestring" .

Answer (score 13):

You can do it with grep alone (without find).

```
grep -riL "somestring" .
```

This is the explanation of the parameters used on `grep`

```
     -L, --files-without-match
             each file processed.
     -R, -r, --recursive
             Recursively search subdirectories listed.

     -i, --ignore-case
             Perform case insensitive matching.
```

If you use `l` lowercase you will get the opposite (files with matches)

```
     -l, --files-with-matches
             Only the names of files containing selected lines are written
```

Answer (score 2):

Find the markdown file through find and grep to find the mismatch

```
$ find. -name '* .md' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -iL "title"
```

Directly use grep's `-L` to search for files that only contain markdown files and no titles

```
$ grep -iL "title" -r ./* --include '* .md'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use "find" the script do "grep" also in folder:

```
[root@vps test]# find  | xargs grep -Li 1234
grep: .: Is a directory
.
./test.txt
./test2.txt
[root@vps test]#
```

Use the "grep" directly:

```
# grep -Li 1234 /root/test/*
/root/test/test2.txt
/root/test/test.txt
[root@vps test]#
```

or specify in "find" the options "-type f"...even if you use the find you will put more time (first the list of files and then make the grep).