# How can we list all files in a directory NOT containing a particular string pattern using find/grep/xargs or any other unix command?

Tags: csh

Suppose I have a directory with a list of files having .log extension and i need to find out those  log files which do not contain abc. How would we do that?

Comment: someone else asked the same question not long ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748129/using-grep-to-find-files-that-doesnt-contain-a-given-string-pattern

Answer (score 2):

```
find .  -not  -ipath '.*log' -exec  grep  -H -E -o -c  "abc"  {} \; | grep :0\$
```

or you could install ack

```
ack -L foo
```