# In Ansible find module how to use negative lookup regex in contains parameter

Tags: ansible

I have multiple `config.properties` files in nested folder which contains my common configuration.

`/myproject/env/dev/config.properties`:

```
LOG_PATH=/app/log
LOG_LEVEL=INFO
CLUSTER=ABC
NAMESPACE=dev
```

`/myproject/env/test/config.properties`:

```
CLUSTER=ABC
NAMESPACE=test
```

I want to list the files for a set of keys like (`LOG_PATH`) not available in `config.properties`.

I am able to do positive lookup (`contains: LOG_PATH`) in contains parameter but when I do negative lookup it shows me both file path as matched but I expect it should show just one path `/test/config.properties`.

Is something wrong in my regex? I verified it using https://pythex.org and it works there. I also used DOTALL regex `^((?!LOG_PATH)[\\s][\\S])*$`

`findFiles-Playbook.yml`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
   - name: List the file path which doesn't contains the content
     find:
        paths: /mrproject/env/
        recurse: yes
        follow: True
        patterns: config.properties
        use_regex: True
        contains: LOG_PATH
        #contains: ^((?!LOG_PATH).)*$ this Negative lookup doesn't works
     register: matched_files

   - name: print matches
     debug:
       var: matched_files
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything works as expected:

- with `contains: LOG_PATH` you search for files which contain `LOG_PATH` (only `/myproject/env/dev/config.properties` contains that line)
- with `^((?!LOG_PATH).)*$` you search for files which contain lines other than starting with `LOG_PATH` (both example files contain such lines)

  - it will exclude file(s) with `LOG_PATH` line(s) only; no other lines

---

There is no way to specify "does not contain" in a single Ansible `find`-module call.

You can either:

- call the module twice: once to find all files matching pattern, the second time with `contains: LOG_PATH` and process the results (`map(attribute='path')` then `difference` filter)
- execute an external command returning the files (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1748129/2947502) for inspiration); there is no change caused by this task anyway, so you can safely add `changed: false` for the task to report `ok`.